# why JQuery serialize() is not working in jquery/Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery/Ajax to submit a form but when I submit it BUT it's return empty value in .php page. I think the jQuery `serialize()` is not getting the data from the FORM. can you please fix it why it's not working ?

**Here is my html code :**

```
<form id="phone_form">
      <table width="290" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-bottom:0px;" id="phoneWraper">    
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><div id="phone_success"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Phone <a href="#" id="addMore">( + )</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>      
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Work :</td>
        <td align="right"><input value="<?php echo $work_phone; ?>" type="text" name="work_phone" id="work_phone" placeholder="work phone"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Mobile :</td>
        <td align="right"><input value="<?php echo $mobile_phone; ?>" type="text" name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone" placeholder="mobile phone"/></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="290" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-bottom:0px;">    
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" class="search_submit" value="Save" id="phone_form_submit"></td>
      </tr>                 
      </table>
   </form>
```

**Here is my JS code :**

```
$("#phone_form_submit").on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'save_phone.php',
    data : $("#phone_form").serialize(),
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

});

Thank You.

In firebug I see this :

[image]

Comment: does developer tools network log confirm that you are sending no data?

Comment: in .php page I used print_r($_REQUEST) to check if any data is return or not. But it's showing empty value.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zdpq9402/

Comment: Is `save_phone.php` in the same directory as your original form?

Comment: yes It's in save directory.

Comment: I mean same directory

Comment: Oh I just solved it. I used another way to get the data. Now It's ok, Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your solution as answer, please?